# Liquibase 3.7.0 generates wrong "createTable" SQL statement missing "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY" for the column with autoIncrement

Tags: oracle, liquibase, auto-increment

After running liquibase update from CLI:

```
java -cp liquibase-core-3.7.0.jar;liquibase-oracle-3.2.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;
slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar liquibase.integration.commandline.Main ...
```

I'm getting following exception:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set ...
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
 [Failed SQL: (907) CREATE TABLE table_name (id NUMBER(38, 0)  (START WITH 10000) NOT NULL, ...
```

This is the changeset:

```
  <changeSet author="changeset_author" id="changeset_id">
    <createTable tableName="table_name" remarks="remarks on table">
      <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT" startWith="10000" remarks="remarks on column">
        <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
      </column>
      ...
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
```

When using liquibase-core-3.6.3, same changeset is successfully executed, having following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id NUMBER(38, 0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10000) NOT NULL, ...
```

So exception is caused by missing "**GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY**" part.

However, i can't use versions 3.6.0-3.6.3 because of slf4j logging issues.

Can someone suggest how to resolve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: did you try 3.8.0?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, i tried 3.8.0, same thing. I opened the issue: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3487. I believe issue is introduced with this commit: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/0484d1ecc61b574aa16187bc6cbff58a2a3f6442

Comment: Tested with liquibase-core 3.8.1. Issue still exists.